# Use Kustomize edit to update a value in my configmap

Tags: configmap, kustomize

Following is my configmap content stores in a file called configmap.yaml:

```
    apiVersion: v1
    data:
      key1: val1
      key2: val2
      key3: val3
    kind: ConfigMap
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      name: job-inputs
      namespace: qa
```

And Following is my content of the kustomization.yaml that is present in the same folder where my configmap sits

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

resources:
- configmap.yaml
```

However, I want to change the values of my data.keys in the config map using kustomize edit cli command.

I did not find the right documentation which could help me. First of all is this possible through kustomize, if so how?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the original file with `kustomize` CLI.

What you can do is write a configmap patch in the `kustomization.yaml` file with something like this:

```yaml
configMapGenerator:
- name: job-inputs
  behavior: merge
  literals:
  - key1=newval1
```

> ConfigMap values from bases may be overridden by adding another generator for the ConfigMap in the overlay and specifying the behavior field. behavior may be one of:
>
> - create (default value): used to create a new ConfigMap. A name conflict error will be thrown if a ConfigMap with the same name and namespace already exists.
> - replace: replace an existing ConfigMap from the base.
> - merge: add or update the values in an existing ConfigMap from the base.

Documentation: https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/kustomization/configmapgenerator/

And if you need to, this configmap patch can (probably) be generated with the CLI using `kustomize create configmap ...`.

Documentation: https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kubectl/create/configmap/